# MySQL syntax error in generated JPA Repository Pageable query: near 'offset x rows fetch first y rows only'

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get some rows from my table with pagination by Spring Boot JPA Repository, but MySQL keeps showing a syntax error in the query that was generated by JPA.
It seems MySQL only supports `limit y offset x`, instead of `offset x rows fetch first y rows only` (I am testing with the first page, `page: 0` and `page_size: 1`

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only' at line 1
```

This is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
    ArrayList<MyEntity> findById(Integer id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

and the generated query by JPA

```
select ... from myTable c1_0 order by c1_0.id desc offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only
```

Perhaps, I am still using JDBC driver for SQL
Here is a part in `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.database=mysql
```

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Hmm...what JDBC driver are you using?  The generated SQL looks like Oracle to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks, I think so. But in my pom.xml, it is mysql-connector-j at 8.0.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is my project is using the configuration from a Spring cloud config server.

The `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` config value was `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`. That's why JPA keep generating SQL query that didn't fully work with MySQL (in my case: *offset* and *limit*).

Changing it back to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` using VM options solved my problem.